# Portaudio: How to record only when there is a sound?

Tags: record, audio, portaudio

I'm using Portaudio in order to record the sound in a .raw file but I would like to start the recording only when there is a sound and stop it when there is a silence.

Is there a way to do this with Portaudio?
If not, do you have any idea about how I could do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Portaudio cannot do what you need.  The solution you are looking for is called Vox.   Internet search vox algorithm and you'll find lots of implementations.  I'm sure there are even libraries that will calculate it for you.  I usually just take the rms of the signal buffer and compare it to a predetermined threshold.  If you don't convert the signal level to dB you will probably be working with values in the range of 0.01 To 0.05.  In dB you should be working in the -50 to -30 range.